# Does the earth's gravity affect horizontal movement?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-mechanics, forces

In a frictionless environment, would the weight of an object affect how hard it is to move it horizontally? Since without friction, there is no horizontal force resisting your applied force, would the object be easy to move?

I am aware of inertia but don't see any reason for it to play a role considering there is no opposing force to your applied force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an ideal frictionless environment on a massive body (such as Earth), no force would oppose horizontal motion. Things are never that ideal, but your point is taken. But inertia still affects how much something will accelerate for a given amount of force applied. This will, in turn, affect how fast it ends up moving. So, even the gentlest force will start the object moving, but the final velocity when you stop pushing is dependent on how massive it is.